# C++ Matrix (elements in RAM not continous)

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, memory, ram

(This needs a litle of context, please read this and then, if you can explain me why is happening this, i would aprecciate your help)

## Some context before...

Ok, in my college they taugh us two ways to make a matrix in C++.

The first way is the classic

```cpp
int matrix[rows][columns];
```

And then, is this:

```
int** matrix = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[columns];
```

In theory, this works like this.

[image: Matrix image]

First, we create a *vector* and then, with the for, we iterate in each space in the vector to create the rows, in the image, first we create the green column and, for each number in the column, we create the rest of the elements in the matrix.

We learned how to use pointers to access positions in the matrix, etc. And everything works fine, but, in one excercise, I needed to sort the matrix, and, my first though was "if the matrix is like a big vector in ram, i should sort it like a vector, but with one pointer in the first element of the matrix", (i sorted matrix like this in c). But when i tried to sort with the bubble algoritm, some RAM *trash* were bringed in the matrix, so.. After a few hours, I tried to see how RAM and the elements in the matrix were allocated, and with the debugger in clion i saw this...

[image]

In this case, each row of the matrix is in continous RAM spaces, but, when a new row is reached, RAM jumps up to 13 positions without reason. I'm not an expert in this topics, so, I created a matrix in the *typical* way to see if this matrix have continous RAM positions and.

[image]

The elements in the matrix are continous in RAM, as I expected

### The question

Why does this happen? I'm not a beginner in programming, so, i know how vectors and matrix suppose to work. But, I'm a begginer in low level, memory manager programming languages (I usually use php, java, python, js, etc, but never c/c++ before college).

And, how C++ knows how to iterate in the matrix?, because if we iterate over the matrix with [i][j] works perfectly, if the elements in the matrix aren't continous, how does c++ knows that if we finished to iterate one row, jump 13 spaces in RAM to the next row?

I appreciate every answer, thank you very much

Comment: 1. When call `new` `rows+1` times, you get `rows+1` separate memory blocks. 2. `a[b]` is defined as `*(a+b)`. I think you need to understand how pointers work, if you're using them without understanding them.

Comment: "because if we iterate over the matrix with [i][j] works perfectly...how does c++ knows that if we finished to iterate one row". You first get `matrix[i]`, which is a pointer `p`, and then we use the pointer to access `p[j]`. In the second method, we don't just store the elements themselves, but we also store `rows` pointers and those pointers are what make it work.

Comment: From my personal experience, the main difficulty in understanding after rewriting `matrix[i][j]` to `*(*(matrix+i)+j)` is that `*(matrix+i)` and `matrix+i` refer to the same memory address in the 1st case, but there is an additional memory address dereference in the 2nd case. This confuses beginners but is just how the language works.

Comment: @WeijunZhou do you know a video, article, or something that helps understand memory like (*(matrix+i)+j)? because idk exacly how this works, i've seen it more than once, but I'd like to understand what does this mean, I'll be gratefull

Comment: We can't control where you can allocate memory (new) , it's kernel job.
So we can't expect address every time when we request memory to kernel.

Comment: I don't know any since I learnt C++ long ago by myself from a book, and I searched a bit on the net but cannot find one that is both beginner-friendly and also does not recommend bad practices such as `using namespace std;`. However you may check the [c++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) to see if you can find anything useful.

Comment: If you want contiguous memory of 2D array and it's known in compile time, then go for `std::array`. But beware of padding.

Comment: @WeijunZhou   When `matrix` and `matrix[i]` are pointers that each contain results of `new` expressions (as in the OP's second approach) then `matrix + i` and *(matrix + i) are NOT guaranteed to be the same memory address (and, in practice, usually are not).    The OP is confused due to incorrectly expecting that, since `int matrix[rows][columns]` produces a contiguous array, that the "matrix" produced by a set of `new` expressions will also be contiguous.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I mean `matrix+i` and `*(matrix+i)` refer to the same address in the 1st case but not the 2nd can be quite confusing to beginners. After all, they **seem to be** the same operator applied to the same type of expressions. The question is really why `matrix[i][j]` without any extra `&` or `*` can work for both cases, whether the memory is contiguous or there is an extra level of indirection.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, this may sounds dumb, but, why `using namespace std;` is a bad practice? I use it in all my projects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @WeijunZhou tysm

Comment: @RicardoRoel [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).  A contiguous array is created, but you keep the `[][]` syntax.

Answer (score 5):

`int matrix[rows][columns];` is contiguous like you say.

`int** matrix = new int*[rows];` is more like

[image]

Each time you call `new` there is no guarantee where the memory will be. the 2nd row could be before the first in memory terms. You don't care as long as you access the columns via the pointers.

Comment: Oh. In this example, the ressulting matrix is 4x3 or 4x4? Because, i understand that the green column is just the _pointers_ to the real matrix (4x3 matrix and not the 4x4 matrix that i though in the begining)

Comment: @RicardoRoel The "green column" does not contain "pointers to the real matrix" (describing it or thinking about it that way is meaningless, and contributes to your misunderstanding).   Each element marked in green is a pointer with a value that is the address of (the first element of) a dynamically allocated (`new`d) array.  There are four pointers, each pointing at the (first element of) a dynamically allocated array with three elements.  So this represents a 4x3 matrix.  Those 3-element arrays each result from a different `new` expression, so are not (required to be) contiguous in memory.

Comment: A typical none-sparse implementation of row-major matrix in C++ would be: `class matrix{std::size_t col; std:: vector<double> storage; public matrix (std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols): col{cols}, storage(rows*cols){};};`. This keeps a costumizable contiguous buffer for the matrix. Accessors and modifiers can easily be added for required level of convenince. `std::vector` is feature reach in terms of size(memory) management and safe to copy, in case deep-copy is needed. If you want C++ code, forget about raw pointers - untill you become ultra expert in C++. Stick to STL, to learn C++ quickly.